# Recognize the email account the URI is clicked from

Tags: rest, email, http, smtp

I'm emailing to user with URI(s) in the message body. When the user will click that URI link, the app will answer the calls depending on the params on the URI.

However, all these should happen depending on which eMail account this URI is clicked from.

Eg. the system sent the email to `thisUser@xyz.com`. Then, the owner of `thisUser@xyz.com` forwarded the message to, say `thatUser@xyz.com`. 
The system should be able to be aware that the URI sent to `thisUser@xyz.com`is being clicked by `thatUser@xyz.com`. Is there a way to make such distinction? How?

I can make the user verify his credentials-- enter his username&passwd but this is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: What's with the tag spam?

Comment: @spectras what do you mean tag spam. snmp is somewhat sideline-- clicking the link isn't anywhere thru it but they all are relevant.

Comment: @spectras mistook smtp with snmp in the previous one

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, as the only information sent to the server is the URI, which is always the same.

Email clients do not send additional information about the recipient of an email to a server when the user clicks on a link in the email. Doing so would be a bad idea, because of privacy concerns, as it could be exploited for, e.g., farming email addresses using chain emails.